# DVWA 1.9 Setup Error

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I was trying to Setup **DVWA 1.9** on **kali linux**. Everything was running okay but When I was trying to connect the database a setup error occurs showing that:

> PHP function allow_url_include: Disabled

I have changed the config.inc.php and also changed php.ini file .

My PHP version: 5.6.24 .

I am running DVWA using XAMPP server .

Can anyone please tell me Why my allow_url_include is disabled when I made all the necessary changes?

> ***Setup Check*****
>
> Operating system: *nix
>
> Backend database: MySQL
>
> PHP version: 5.6.24
>
> Web Server SERVER_NAME: 127.0.0.1
>
> PHP function display_errors: Enabled (Easy Mode!)
>
> PHP function safe_mode: Disabled
>
> PHP function allow_url_include: Disabled
>
> PHP function allow_url_fopen: Enabled
>
> PHP function magic_quotes_gpc: Disabled
>
> PHP module php-gd: Installed
>
> reCAPTCHA key: 6LdK7xITAAzzAAJQTfL7fu6I-0aPl8KHHieAT_yJg
>
> Writable folder /opt/lampp/htdocs/dvwa/hackable/uploads/: Yes)
>
> Writable file /opt/lampp/htdocs/dvwa/external/phpids/0.6/lib/IDS/tmp
>   /phpids_log.txt: Yes***

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I fixed it by going into the `php.ini` file and editing the `allow_url_include` option

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_fopen = 1

allow_url_open = On
allow_url_open = 1
```

I changed both `fopen` and `open` because of some advice I got off a forum in regards to this issue and it worked for me.

Comment: Hey Paul, sorry for the incorrect format, I'm new to Stackoverflow. Any advice on where I could learn better format ? Thanks